# Rails 4 Devise Login in partial page POPUP window in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, popover

Am using devise for login and registration, normal sessions/new lgin working good. But now i want login page in partial page model window.

_partial_page.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="tab-content lighten-5">
            <div id="sign_in_tab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h5>Sign In</h5>
                <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
                    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :id=>"icon_prefix",class:"validate" %>
                    <label for="icon_prefix">Your Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off",:id=>"icon_prefix",class:"validate" %>
                    <label for="icon_telephone">Your Password</label>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <%= f.check_box :remember_me,:id=>"icon_prefix",class:"validate" %>
                    <label>Remember Me</label>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

applicaion_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def resource_class
    devise_mapping.to
  end

end
```

Now when login it shows blank page not logingin.

Comment: What is your problem? Now if you click on login, it shows blank page?

Comment: When i click login window get hang..

Comment: Can you post the code for that login button?

Comment: devise uses its own views but if you want yours own , to need to make changes in `devise.rb` for more information goto devise docs